# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.pdftron.pdf.PDFNet.setTempPath

Tags: android, pdftron

I'm getting this exception when calling PDFNet.initialize in an ARMv8 architecture device (android app). The app is working great in other devices but is failing on this one.

I've added the .so correctly, as you can see here:

[image]

So, I really can't see the problem and it's crashing no matter how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to follow the official guide on how to integrate with PDFTron library here:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/android/guides/getting-started/integrate-manual.

Or try out a quick start sample shown here: https://github.com/PDFTron/pdf-viewer-android

Comment: I've read it but I don't find the solution there (it doesn't even talk about the .so files). Do you know a more specific direction to follow?

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela If you are looking at the latest version, there should be no so files or jar files, it got changed to library aar format. So I would recommend you to follow the guide exactly.